# Can't get OpenGL view to work in QT application

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt-creator

I'm trying to make a QT application with open GL, but no matter what I do I can't get it to do anything, it just renders blackness.

```
void GraphView::initializeGL()
{
    qglClearColor(Qt::black);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0 , 256.0, 256.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(0    , 0   , 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0    , 128.0 , 0.0);
    glVertex3f(128.0, 128.0 , 0.0);
    glVertex3f(128.0, 0   , 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

the only thing I've been able to get it to do is color the screen red by changing the clear color to red.  But even then if I add the following code:

```
void GraphView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qglClearColor(Qt::red);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
}
```

It seems to do absolutely nothing; but the color will change if the window resizes--the resize method is just an empty `{ }` affair.  But if I open a second window in the same application with another GLwidget, it displays part of the firefox window, typically the bookmarks.  I'm not sure if there's any particular reason for that; but it doesn't seem to display any other application.

Comment: I don't know QT, but it seems suspicious that you have your drawing code in a method named `initializeGL()`. If the name is any indication, that will only be called once on initialization, not on every redraw.

Comment: Originally it was in the redraw function, but now I just have that as an empty function because I thought there might be a problem with it, and that was why it wasn't drawing anything.

Comment: As @reto-koradi says, having the drawing code in `initializeGL` is not the way to go.  Your best bet would be to take a look at the [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets-opengl.html) and work from there.